# Completing a class definition

Tags: java, constructor, variable-assignment

Suppose that you are given the following PetDriver class, which includes a main method:

```
public class PetDriver{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    int weight = 40;
    Pet doggie = new Pet("Rover", weight);
    System.out.println("my pet's name is " + doggie.getName());
    System.out.println("my pet's weight is " + doggie.getWeight());
  }
}
```

Executing main produces the following output:

my pet's name is Rover
my pet's weight is 40

My code is as follows but It is returning null.

```
public class pet {

    public String name;
    public int weight = 40;

    public Pet (String y, int x){
        y = name;
        x = weight;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public int getWeight(){
        return weight;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In your constructor, you should do it the other way around:

```
public Pet (String y, int x){
  name = y;    // instead of y = name
  weight = x;  // instead of x = weight
}
```

What you did was assigning the member value to the parameters of the constructor, instead of the other way around. Therefore the member value `name`itself was never written, and therefore it was `null`.

Answer (score 2):

Your constructor does not assign the value to the properties. Change them to the following.

```
public Pet (String y, int x){
  name = y;
  weight = x;
}
```